# RESTful API URI design: hierarchy

Tags: rest

Having the models shown below, where a User (admin) can have multiple Places, Places can be managed by multiple Users (non-admin), and Places can have many Tables, many Customers, Sections and so on:

```
                --> Table
User <--> Place --> Customer
                --> Section

Notation: <--> many to many
           --> one to many
```

Is this RESTful API implementation well designed according the REST guidelines? I'm not sure whether should I implement the API using hierarchical levels or not.

REST API, including HTTP valid methods for each endpoint in between brackets:

```
/api/places                            [GET, POST]
/api/places/<name>                     [GET, PUT, DELETE]
/api/places/<name>/customers           [GET, POST]
/api/places/<name>/customers/<id>      [GET, PUT, DELETE]
/api/places/<name>/tables              [GET, POST]
/api/places/<name>/tables/<id>         [GET, PUT, DELETE]
/api/places/<name>/users               [GET, POST]
/api/places/<name>/users/<username>    [GET, PUT, DELETE]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST does not have guidelines in terms of how your url hierarchy should be defined.

Your url design looks fine enough enough to give a human an idea of how your api is structured.

Comment: Do you think would be possible to remove the hierarchy and use instead: /api/customers,  /api/users, ... and pass the "place" reference in the http request?

Comment: Yea, that's totally possible too. The point is that there's many different ways to approach this, and no agreed upon best practice. If you're really new to this I would make sure you're using an existing hypermedia format (like HAL or Siren), and follow a design similar to a well-built existing API.